# PEAR upgrage from Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.2 into Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.3

Tags: php, pear

Command in command line to upgrade the spread sheet module.

> from Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.2 into
>   Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.3.

As well i would like to know, is there any big diff between

Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.2 and Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.3

Comment: pear upgrade Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find that the changelog is [here](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/download/), and that page also gives you the command line to install the 0.9.3 version